# Why do you get an increase in bicarbonate ions after vomiting?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, neuroscience

Why do you get an increase in bicarbonate ions after vomiting?

Comment: Welcome. Any prior research you can share with us? Importantly, where did you find your statement that vomiting increases HCO3- and *where* is it increased? In the blood? Saliva? Stomach?.

Comment: Although you need to show some effort , but I wanted to give you a hint - after vomiting quite a good amount of $H^+$ ions are lost (that’s because HCl is lost) now think what would happen to extracellular fluid to balance this change :)